# Get coordinates of .pbf/.osm of ways and relations directly?

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinates, ogr2ogr, pbf

Is there a tool for pbf or osm files so that I can see the coordinates of ways and relations directly? Currently ways have only references to nodes. So if I want to have the coordinates of a way, I must search for the nodes before and then read the coordinates of the nodes and then put it into the way.
When I have a pbf of a whole country this process takes much time.
I am working in java. I am open to make some preperation before the reading of the pbf.
I have already read that it can work with ogr2ogr or osm2pgsql but I am not sure how to use them for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get the geometry of ways and relations directly. The OSM data model is based on nodes-ways-relations https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements. Steve Coast has written a blog post as a defense of that model https://stevecoast.substack.com/p/in-defense-of-openstreetmaps-data.

However, you are right that you can pre-process the OSM data with for example ogr2ogr or osm2pgsql. Then you will have point geometries, line geometries, polygon geometries, and relation geometries which you can access directly. About how to use the tools, I suggest to read their documentation and have a try. The GDAL OSM driver documentation is at https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/osm.html and it includes also a few ogr2ogr examples.